# C# add properties to an existing class at runtime

Tags: c#, xtrareport, typebuilder

I hava a class like;

```
    public class MainClass
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
        public int Property3 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Class2
    {
        public Class2()
        {
            List1 = new List<Class1>();
        }
        public string Property4 { get; set; }
        public List<Class1> List1 { get; set; }
    }
    public List<Class2> List2 { get; set; }
    public string Property5 { get; set; }
    public bool Property6 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add parameters in MainClass at runtime

```
    public class MainClass
{
    ...
    public string Parameter1 { get; set; }
    public string Parameter2 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

or create new class with inheritance existing class.

```
    public class NewClass : MainClass
{
    public string Parameter1 { get; set; }
    public string Parameter2 { get; set; }
}
```

or something else. These's my ideas. Unfortunately, using a dictionary will not solve my problem because I am using xtrareport and I must show a fieldlist.

Comment: I think it will be good to explain where this need comes from. There might be a better solution for that

Comment: Could you explain what you’re trying to achieve? This might be an XY problem, meaning your original problem could be solved in a completely different way if we know what it is

Comment: Check out ExpandoObject.  Or, just use a Dictionary.

Comment: Why are those classes nested?

Comment: I don't want change project when end-user wants new field from me. I want solve at interface and create report with these parameters

Comment: Then you most likely need a Dictionary, or simply a list of Key/Value pairs.

Comment: unfortunatelly dictionary is not solve my problem because i am using xtrareport and i must show fieldlist.

Comment: It would have been nice if you'd included that detail in your original question.  How does xtrareport show a field list?

Comment: This is probably a better question for DevExpress than us.  They can tell you how to bind to an arbitrary list of Key/Value pairs or create customizable reports at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind your **ExtraReport** to a **DataSet** instead of binding to collection of a **strong typed objects** (which can't be changed at execution-time). So if you add new fields to the data-source it’s a matter of changing the report for showing that new fields. If you create a **Stored Procedure** to retrieve data, you can even change the query without having to compile the **Application**. *You can iterate through the **DataTable** object of the DataSet to read all the fields & place them dynamically using **XRBinding DevExpress Objects***.

See: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T408680/binding-datatable-object-to-xtrareport-xrtable

Comment: Thank you but I don't use database i use xml file it is a simple program